# TimesTen difference between two timestamps

Tags: sql, timesten

I would like to get difference between two columns (both TT_TIMESTAMP(26,6)) `select timestamp1 - timestamp2 as diff from table;` but getting this error: `An interval data type must be specified for a datetime arithmetic result`

Any ideas?

Comment: What database are you using? (I can't find any references via a web search to TT_TIMESTAMP)

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you would need to provide an internal type (year,month,day ect) that would identify the specific element that you are wanting to se the differance in.

A formula like the following should give you the differance in days for example in T-SQL:

DATEDIFF(day, timestamp1, timestamp2) AS DateDiff

[W3 Schools has a good indicator of the various options you can use](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp)

Comment: `DATEDIFF` is rather different between different database engines. For example, MySQL DATEDIFF only takes two dates/timestamps.

Comment: cheers for pointing that our, Ive changed my answer to specifically referance T-SQL. When the OP hasent been clear in their question on what engine they are using, as MySQL dosent have Interval datatypes I presumed that the question was referanceing an engine that does (T-SQL or PostgreSQL ect)

Answer (score 0):

[TimestTen 18.1 Documentation Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/timesten-18.1/TTSQL/types.htm#TTSQL155)

For TimesTen Database,

The difference between the two `TT_TIMESTAMP` datatype columns results into an `INTERVAL` datatype. (Not `TT_TIMESTAMP`)

And to get the desired component of the `INTERVAL` datatype, we must use `EXTRACT` function.

Below is one example.

```
-- Data preparation
CREATE TABLE DEMO (A TT_TIMESTAMP, B TT_TIMESTAMP;

INSERT INTO DEMO VALUES (TT_TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 01:01:01.000000', TT_TIMESTAMP '2022-01-05 01:01:01.000000');
```

```
-- Below will return an error (as expected)
SELECT B-A FROM DEMO;

2789: An interval data type must be specified for a datetime arithmetic result
The command failed.
```

So, for the actual difference, we need to calculate like below.

```
-- Extract data like below
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM B-A) FROM DEMO;
< 4 >
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM B-A) FROM DEMO;
< 0 >
SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM B-A) FROM DEMO;
< 0 >
SELECT EXTRACT(SECOND FROM B-A) FROM DEMO;
< 0 >
```

```
-- Get SECONDS between two TT_TIMESTAMP columns
SELECT 
  (EXTRACT(DAY FROM B-A) * 24 * 3600
  + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM B-A) * 3600
  + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM B-A) * 60
  + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM B-A)) 
FROM 
  demo;

< 345600 >
```